# Listing of All Mysql Data Types and Syntax For All Settings

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm looking for a listing of all MySQL data types and the available settings for each option  for each data type.

After a bit of googling I couldn't find anything quite like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[here](http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-notes/mysql-notes/mysql-data-types-50.file) you can find a quick summary of mysql data types, with range, attributes and default value

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake, don't forget the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html).

Although the list is broken across multiple pages, often with a lot of commentary in between, it's a useful resource when you need to check some aspect of a particular type. There are also overviews of the basic types, but again, there's a lot of cruft mixed in with it.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone ever needs them as a json array:

`"[\"TINYINT[(M)]\", \"SMALLINT[(M)]\", \"MEDIUMINT[(M)]\", \"INT[(M)]\", \"BIGINT[(M)]\", \"FLOAT(p)\", \"FLOAT[(M,D)]\", \"DOUBLE[(M,D)]\", \"DECIMAL[(M,[D])]\", \"BIT[(M)]\", \"CHAR[(M)]\", \"VARCHAR(M)\", \"TINYTEXT\", \"TEXT\", \"MEDIUMTEXT\", \"LONGTEXT\", \"BINARY[(M)]\", \"VARBINARY(M)\", \"TINYBLOB\", \"BLOB\", \"MEDIUMBLOB\", \"LONGBLOB\", \"ENUM(\\\"A1\\\",\\\"A2\\\",...)\", \"SET(\\\"A1\\\",\\\"A2\\\",...)\", \"DATE\", \"DATETIME\", \"TIME\", \"TIMESTAMP\", \"YEAR\"]"`